# Errors while trying to configure Solr 5.3.1 on Windows 10

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I'm trying to setup a very basic configuration of Solr, to read some text from a mysql table and index it. I'm following the steps in [DIH Quick Start document](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart).

The document doesn't tell you where to place `solrconfig.xml`.

At first I tried placing it under the solr5.3.1 folder (next to bin). That failed. Then I noticed the "add core" button was looking for it in server\solr\new_core. So I put it there, but then got this other error:
[image]

My data import handler looks like this:

```
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

And here's data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/ctcrets" 
              user="root" 
              password="xxxx"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="id" 
            query="select RETS_STAGE1_QUEUE_ID as id, LN_LIST_NUMBER as name, xmlText as desc from RETS_STAGE1_QUEUE">
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The document assumes you already know the solr.home [1] directory structure. On top of that, I think it assumes you started the sample Solr instance (e.g. ./solr start -p 8984) where everything should be already set.

Once started you can see on the dashboard where the configuration is exactly located. Go there, change the files as suggested and RELOAD the core through the admin console (CoreAdmin). If you want you can also do a stop / restart.

As side notes:

1. the DIH is not part of the Solr core, so you should put some "lib" directive within the solrconfig.xml, as far as I remember, the sample config already has those directives so you don't need to "import" the DIH lib
2. the JDBC driver that allows the connection with the database is not included so your classpath (i.e. JVM or Solr classpath - through the same lib directive) must include this additional lib(s).

---

[1] http://www.solrtutorial.com/configuring-solr.html